# Setting transparency of itemrenderers in spark list

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, colors, itemrenderer

I have a list that has alternating item colors.

```
<s:List id="myList" change="selectionChanged(event)" alternatingItemColors="[0x000000, 0xFFFFFF]" dataProvider="{alResults}" itemRenderer="itemRenders.Results" width="100%"></s:List>
```

I just simply want the item backgrounds to be transparent.

In the opening tag of the ItemRenderer, I tried this, but didn't work.

```
<s:ItemRenderer name="Results"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    autoDrawBackground="true"
    contentBackgroundAlpha="0.2">
```

I tried setStyle in the data override method as well, and didn't work either.  Thanks.

Comment: ItemRenderers are transparent by default (except on rollover when `autoDrawBackground="true"`
). It is the List that has a background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is to try adding transparency to the actual colors.

```
alternatingItemColors="[0x33000000, 0x33FFFFFF]"
```

If my math is right the 33 in hex would be around 0.2 alpha.

I've never done it in Flex but I've used it multiple times in Flash. Worth at least a try.

Comment: Did this actually worked? I can't seem to make it happen... im setting both colors to 0x00000000, which should be transparent black so to speak, but instead of the background I have on the list, I get a black background per list item.

Answer (score 5):

**ItemRenderer**: `autoDrawBackground="false"` will disable its background.

**List**: you can use `contentBackgroundColor` to change background color or `contentBackgroundAlpha="0"` to make it transparent.